# Is there a way to insert an "if" statement into a libreoffice writer formula?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

so, recently I've learnt that it is actually possible to use formulas on libreoffice writer tables (such as  G 2 Ecc.).
My question is the following: is it possibile to use "if" statements into those formulas?
I know that in libreoffice calc lets you use formulas like "=IF (A=B;C;D)" so I'm wondering if there exist some similar statement in writer too.

Comment: If the result of your hypothetical formula is a text string (for example, "paid" otherwise "not paid") you can do something similar in Writer using [Field-Functions](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.0/en-US/text/swriter/01/04090003.html). If we are talking about a numerical result, then you can use the sum formula, where each term is the result of multiplying the expected result by a condition. For example, `= (<A1> eq <B1>) * <C1> + (<A1> neq <B1>) * <D1>` - corresponds to the formula `= IF (<A1> = <B1>; <C1>; <D1 >)`

Comment: Ok, that sound exactly like what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!